# How to print each item in the dictionary randomly without repeating?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

How could I print each question from the dictionary randomly without repeating?

Every time I run this command, I get repeated questions.

```
import random

capitals = {
    "Canada": "Toronto",
    "Spain": "Madrid",
    "Germany": "Berlin",
    "Belgium": "Brussels",
    "Australia": "Sydney",
}

for country, capital in capitals.items():
    country = random.choice(list(capitals.keys()))

    capital = capitals[country]
    question = input(f"What is the capital of {country}? : ")
    if question == capital:
        print("Congratulations!\n")

    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The correct answer: {capital}\n")
```

Comment: I don't get any repeated question from your `code`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that you called `random.choice(list(capitals.keys()))` 5 times and since every call is independent you got the same value more than once and didn't get at all some of the other values

in my code, I shuffled a list of your keys and then iterated over it , and since it was shuffled i picked different (random) country each time

this should do the trick :

```
import random

capitals = {
    "Canada": "Toronto",
    "Spain": "Madrid",
    "Germany": "Berlin",
    "Belgium": "Brussels",
    "Australia": "Sydney",
}
shuffeled_keys = list(capitals.keys())
random.shuffle(shuffeled_keys)
for country in shuffeled_keys:
    capital = capitals[country]
    question = input(f"What is the capital of {country}? : ")
    if question == capital:
        print("Congratulations!\n")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The correct answer: {capital}\n")
```

If you have any questions about y code feel free to ask me in the comments, and if my comment helped you please consider marking it as the answer :)

Comment: I appreciate your comment but the result is the same.
I ran your code in VS Code and the result printed Australia twice and Germany did not appear

Comment: are you sure? I just tried it 3 times and it worked fine,
could you try running my code as it is without changing it? (i don't know if you did but just in case :) )

and if it ends up working, could you mark my comment as the answer?

Comment: you could add `print(shuffeled_keys)` before the for loop to see the order of the countries you are going to get

Comment: I tried it a few times and it worked. I probably made some mistakes the first time.
Thanks !